# How to prepopulate dropdown fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo html grid which has editable data rows. When the edit button is selected on a particular row, a modal pops up containing a subset of the fields from the row which can be edited. Each field in the modal is a drop down list (containing all possible entries for each field as returned from SQL queries) where the user can select one value from each list.

The issue is that right now, each field isn't being pre-populated with the values from the actual grid row and instead, each field starts out with the first value of the lists returned from the sql queries. To clarify, each grid row contains the following html structure:

```
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr role="row" data-uid="6f0062a8-878a-47b9-8185-6bf71523452">
<td role="gridcell" style="display: none;">232</td>
<td role="gridcell">1000</td>
<td role="gridcell">Value 1</td>
<td role="gridcell">2000</td>
<td role="gridcell">Value 2</td>
<td role="gridcell">3000</td>
<td role="gridcell">Value 3</td>
<td role="gridcell">Value 4</td>
<td role="gridcell">4000</td>
<td role="gridcell"><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Edit" href="#"><span class=" "></span>Edit</a><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Remove" href="#"><span class=" "></span>Remove</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The column values that appear in the modal are the ones containing the word "Value." On click of the edit button in each row, the following function gets called to get the selected row:

```
 function showEdit(e) {
        currentRow = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $('#editPopUp').data('kendoWindow').open().center().toFront();
    }
```

which calls the following code for the modal:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
        .Name("editPopUp")
        .Scrollable(false)
        .Width(500)
        .Height(300)
        .Modal(true)
        .Title("Edit Report")
        .Visible(false)
    .Content(@<text>
            <div>
                <div class="addReports">
                    <div>

                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()


                          .Name("Value1Edit")
                          .DataTextField("Text")
                          .DataValueField("Value")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                  .BindTo(ViewData["value1"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                        )
                        )
                    </div>
                    <div>

                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                          .Name("Value2Edit")
                          .DataTextField("Text")
                          .DataValueField("Value")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                  .BindTo(ViewData["value2"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                        )
                        )
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                          .Name("Value3Edit")
                          .DataTextField("Text")
                          .DataValueField("Value")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                  .BindTo(ViewData["value3"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                        )
                        )

                    </div>
                    <div>

                        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                          .Name("Value4Edit")
                          .DataTextField("Text")
                          .DataValueField("Value")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                  .BindTo(ViewData["value4"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                        )
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**How can the field values from the table row be passed to the modal to prepopulate it's fields?**

Answer (score 2):

You can set the dropdown value at runtime when opening the window:

```
function showEdit(e) {
    currentRow = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    let wnd = $('#editPopUp').data('kendoWindow');

    wnd.bind("open", function () {
        let $element = this.element,
            ddl1 = $element.find('#Value1Edit').data("kendoDropDownList"); // If the selector '#Value1Edit' doens't works, try by name attr '[name="Value1Edit"]', i'm not sure how kendo generates asp.net mvc widgets names/ids

        dd1.value(currentRow.Value1);
    });

    wnd.open().center().toFront();
}
```

Do that for all dropdown widgets you have in the window. You can also save some code and create a function for that if you have too many dropdowns:

```
let fillDropDowns = function fillDropDowns($element, data, valuesCount) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= valuesCount; i++) {
         $element.find(`#ValueEdit${i}`).data("kendoDropDownList").value(data[`Value${i}`])
    });
}
```

And call it like this inside the open event:

```
fillDropDowns($element, currentRow, 3);
```

That function will try to populate 3 dropdowns with name `ValueEdit1`, `ValueEdit2` and `ValueEdit3` with the keys `Value1`, `Value2` and `Value3` from the `currentRow`.

Comment: In the statement `let $element = this.element,...` there is an error saying that a semicolon is expected after the statement `$element.find('#Value1Edit').data("kendoDropDownList")`. Is this issue being caused by a difference in the versions we're using?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 nope, that was an error in the code I have provided. Fixed it. It was a colon at the end of the line `ddl1 = $element.... `.

Comment: Ok, also, where is .Value1 coming from? I'm getting"value1", "value2", etc. from the view data dictionary and there is .DataValueField("Value") in the dropdown list definition, but I'm not using Value1 (with a capital V) anywhere.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 it is an example, I don't know how your data is structured, you didn't showed. `Value1` should be the dropdown related value in your grid data.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to get the text of the grid cells with text "value (i)" like: `<td role="gridcell">Value 1</td>`. I tried doing  ddl1.value(currentRow.element.find('td:nth-child(3)').text());` but I got the error `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`. How can I extract the text of the four grid cells from the current row variable?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 `currentRow` should be an javascript object, not an element, this should work: `currentRow.Value1`.

Comment: Ok, logging that to the console does show the data. For some reason though, the default values for the dropdowns are all empty. I tried using both options for referencing the dropdowns as outlined in your answer (i.e `find('#Value1Edit')` and `[name="Value1Edit"]`) . Does anything look incorrect? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5N6LoRH1NP

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 you must check three things, i think: the value(that you already said its correct), the dropdown at the time you try to set the value(dropdown's reference etc..) and if the dropdown has a data with the same *id* as you're trying to set. By *id*  you can understand as the [model id](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/fields/id), which tells the datasource which data field it has to take as the widget's value.

Comment: I tried setting the dropdown list values to random strings and the text in the box is still not showing up (e.g. `ddl1.value("test data");`). I also tried directly setting the value attribute on the html itself (`.Value("test value")`) and the field was still blank. Is there another way to set the value of the field other than using the value attribute, which seems to be not working?